# In ggplot, why does one have to separately set axis.text.x and axis.text.y to element_blank() instead of just axis.text?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This code produces this plot:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg))+
    geom_line()+
    theme(axis.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

Where it seems that `axis.text` argument doesn't work. In order to make it work, one needs to do this:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg))+
    geom_line()+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

My question is why?

Comment: The code you provided does not match the plot you printed. Maybe you add `+theme_classic()` after this code, and so your `theme()` arguments are replaced by the new theme you selected

Answer (score 2):

`axis.text` according to document:

> tick labels along axes (element_text; inherits from text)

When I run your code it does work:

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.1.2
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg))+
  geom_line()+
  theme(axis.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>